# PLSQL script not exporting the spool in two different format (i.e .csv and .log) for the same output

Tags: oracle, plsql, append, spool

I want to export the spool in two different format for the below given sample but unluckily, spool Main_Spool.log is not collecting all the output. Is there is any possibility/alternative way to do this ?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF

SPOOL Main_Spool.log
DECLARE 
...................
BEGIN 
<QUERY - 1>
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First Output');
END;
/
DECLARE 
................
BEGIN      
<QUERY - 2>
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Second Output');
END; 
/
SPOOL OFF
/
SPOOL Main_Spool.log append
SPOOL CSV_Format_spool.csv
DECLARE 
................
BEGIN      
<QUERY - 2>
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Third Output');
END;
/
SPOOL OFF
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spool` can only write to one file at a time. You will need to use OS commands to copy it, e.g.

```
host copy Main_Spool.log CSV_Format_spool.csv
```

Or spool everything to separate files and then combine them as you need using host commands:

```
host type file1 file2 > file3
```

By the way, the `/` character executes whatever is in the SQL buffer, so the script above will execute the `'Second Output'` block twice.

Comment: Thank you. HOST COPY command is working but it's just like replacing.  Main_Spool.log hold (First Output Second Output). If we use "HOST COPY Main_Spool.log CSV_Format_spool.csv" CSV_Format_spool.csv will also contain same as Main_Spool.log. I want only Main_Spool.log have all the outputs and CSV_Format_spool.csv should contain only that particular block output (Third Output). Is this possible? can we use append in HOST COPY command? Kindly help

Comment: No, `copy` is just the Windows file copy command. However you can concatenate files using `type` - example added above.